# library not found for -lAppAuth

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I try build IPA file on Xcode from .xcodeproj file and I obtain next error log:

```
library not found for -lAppAuth
```

And I never installed that package.

After that, I've decided to install this package, but error continues

### Steps:

- Generic iOS device
- Product>Archive

[image: error log]

### Enviroment

- React v16.9.0
- React Native v0.61.2
- MacOS Movaje 10.14.3
- Xcode 10.3 (not update because i can't update OS)

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the setting of build active architecture to No in Build Settings tab of your project.